# get image to respect the width of a screen using bootstrap

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to build a responsive site however I cant seem to get an image to stay within the width of the screen, it just overflows. I use a well or a container and I get an ugly border with loads of wasted space. How can I get a picture, no border onto my page?

Here is my code that works with a container but the container has a border which I can't touch as I use containers elsewhere any i ant their borders.

```
<div class="row hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img src="img/home/image.png" alt="homePlate">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give it `img-responsive` class: `<img class="img-responsive" src="img/home/image.png" alt="homePlate">`

Comment: Nice one, that worked. Can i remove the small border?

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer. I think the border is from the thumbnail class.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give you image the [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) class. This is defined in Bootstrap as:

```
.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

So you image would be:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/home/image.png" alt="homePlate">
```

Also, the border is likely coming from the `thumbnail` class you are applying to the `a`. Remove that and the border will go.